# Authorizing with hd (hosted domain) param (G+ API): Google doesn't show any tip for client, who is trying to use his personal google-account

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, authorization, google-plus, google-oauth

After user clicks "*Sign in with your corporate account*" button on our corporate site, "*Google Plus API*" is redirecting user to "*Choose an account*" page.

When the client tries to *Sign in* with his **personal (not domain-hosted, "corporate") Google-account**, -- he is redirected to "***Choose an account***" page ***again***, without any tip or suggestion about why he cannot log in.

How to make Google show info about the log-in process?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same issue.